# Is it possible to get MySQL to use a single file in development?

Tags: mysql

Basically, I want MySQL to run everything out of a single file. I work on projects that use MySQL, and I run local servers on my computers, but it's kind of difficult to get them synced. Is it possible to have my local MySQL server use a single file to store the databases so I can sync that file with another computer?

I don't really care about performance, I would only use something like this in my development environment.

Comment: SQLite might do it for you.

Comment: SQLite is great for development, but the projects I'm working on are already using MySQL. I only need this for development, on the production server we're using a proper MySQL database server.

Comment: why on earth does this matter?

Comment: @e4c5 Productivity mostly. It takes a long time to import the database every time I sit down to do some work.

Comment: whether the database is in 1001 files or 1 file the time is the same.

Comment: @e4c5 Oh I see your point. I guess the questions should have been structured differently, maybe "How do I get MySQL to use a certain folder to store its files", or something similar.

Comment: Why not use replication for synchronization, as intended? And on the other hand what is so difficult about copying many small files as opposed to one big one?

Comment: Well, you're right, many small files wouldn't be a problem, as long as they're in one place. Also, what do you mean by replication and synchronization as intended?

Comment: Not sure if I am stating the obvious, but MySQL is a server, and you can connect to it from everywhere (assuming you set it up that way). If you set up your other workstations to connect to that one server instead of having local servers everywhere, it will have the same effect as what I think you mean by "have one file": they all access the same data. Or you sync your servers by replication (but it will make some things more complicated).

Comment: Yeah that might be what I do. The issue is I always need a decent internet connection, which I don't always have, but it's certainly a good option to consider.

Comment: I was under the impression that the "single file" in your original scenario implied some kind of network resource (e.g. a file on a NAS or the cloud) anyway (so that the network connection was implied). Depending on how you are working, you could also use a portable installation, and keep the server and the data directory on e.g. a (fast) usb drive, carry it around and plug it in wherever you need it. You would start the server from the drive and access it like a local installation. (But then you have only one working server, only at the place where you/the drive currently are.)

Comment: Well I meant to put it on my dropbox. It will sync, but stay local that way. But it looks like you're right I will just have to find another way (or just keep deleting and importing the database each time anything changes).

Answer (score 0):

You could use the handy `mysqldump` utility. This is a command that generates every query required to duplicate your database and stores them in a single `.sql` file, which you can then run on any machine you'd like to copy your database to.

[MySQL Reference link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysqldump-sql-format.html)

Comment: That's actually what I've been using. This only works if I import the entire database every single time I work on the database, which is fairly slow.